# Error 1016: Operand of increment must be a reference

Tags: flash

In flash CS6, I am getting an error saying `Error 1016: Operand of increment must be a reference`

Here is my code:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainLoop);
function mainLoop (e:Event)
{
    gg_mc.y= mouseY;
    gg_mc.x= mouseX;
    for (var I = 0; I < numChildren; 1++)
    {
        if (getChildAt(I) is block)
        {
            var b = getChildAt(I) as block;
            if (b.hitTestObject(gg_mc))
            {
                trace ("You got hit")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `for` loop you have to increment your *iteration variable*, which is `I` in your case, not `1`. I think this must be a typing error because `1` looks like `I` so to avoid that you can use `i` instead of `I` :

```
for (var i = 0; i < numChildren; i++){

    ...

}
```